# Track a machine who is entering bad passwords into a samba3 domain controller

Tags: linux, ldap, authentication, samba

I have a user who is getting its account locked constantly because an other machine is trying to login with an old and bad password and thus locking the user's account...

The user doesn't know which machine could be doing this...

Is there any way to get the IP of the remote machine trying to login? I already dived the logs and nothing clear appears...

BTW the authentication is made with LDAP.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't write how did you "split logs" and I assume you did it in wrong way. Add to your `smb.conf` file to the `[global]` section bellow line:

`# log files split per-machine:
log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m`

Now in `/var/log/samba/` you should see:

`[root@server samba]# ls -l
total 52
drwx------. 5 root root              43 Jan 28 05:40 cores
-rw-r--r--  1 root root               0 Jun  3 03:45 log.
-rw-r--r--  1 root root               0 May 28 20:42 log.10.0.6.100
....
-rw-r--r--  1 root root               0 May 29 03:31 log.winxp
...`

Optionally you can try to make samba more verbose by setting:
`log level = 2` or even `3`. (Also `[global]` section)

If your LDAP server is OpenLDAP then try to debug it as well. You can add:
`loglevel        512` to `slapd.conf` and configure rsyslog to redirect LDAP logs to another file instead `/var/log/messages` or `syslog` or `debug` by adding to `rsyslog.conf`:

`local4.* -/var/log/ldap.log`

Example output:

```
Jan 28 22:05:40 server slapd[1348]: conn=1155 op=0 BIND dn="uid=administrator,ou=users,dc=intranet,dc=company,dc=com,dc=pl" method=128
Jan 28 22:05:40 server slapd[1348]: conn=1155 op=0 BIND dn="uid=administrator,ou=users,dc=intranet,dc=company,dc=com,dc=pl" mech=SIMPLE ssf=0
Jan 28 22:05:40 server slapd[1348]: conn=1155 op=0 RESULT tag=97 err=0 text=
Jan 28 22:05:40 server slapd[1348]: conn=1155 op=1 SRCH base="uid=a.kozlowska,ou=users,dc=intranet,dc=company,dc=com,dc=pl" scope=0 deref=0 filter="(&(objectClass=*))"
Jan 28 22:05:40 server slapd[1348]: conn=1155 op=1 SRCH attr=* +
Jan 28 22:05:40 server slapd[1348]: conn=1155 op=1 SEARCH RESULT tag=101 err=0 nentries=1 text=
Jan 28 22:05:40 server slapd[1348]: conn=1155 op=2 SRCH base="uid=a.kozlowska,ou=users,dc=intranet,dc=company,dc=com,dc=pl" scope=0 deref=0 filter="(&(objectClass=*))"
Jan 28 22:05:40 server slapd[1348]: conn=1155 op=2 SRCH attr=* 1.1
Jan 28 22:05:40 server slapd[1348]: conn=1155 op=2 SEARCH RESULT tag=101 err=0 nentries=1 text=
Jan 28 22:05:40 server slapd[1348]: conn=1155 op=3 SRCH base="uid=a.kozlowska,ou=users,dc=intranet,dc=company,dc=com,dc=pl" scope=0 deref=0 filter="(&(objectClass=*))"
Jan 28 22:05:40 server slapd[1348]: conn=1155 op=3 SRCH attr=+ creatorsName createTimestamp modifiersName modifyTimestamp hasSubordinates pwdChangedTime
Jan 28 22:05:40 server slapd[1348]: conn=1155 op=3 SEARCH RESULT tag=101 err=0 nentries=1 text=
Jan 28 22:05:40 server slapd[1348]: conn=1155 op=4 SRCH base="uid=a.kozlowska,ou=users,dc=intranet,dc=company,dc=com,dc=pl" scope=1 deref=0 filter="(objectClass=*)"
Jan 28 22:05:40 server slapd[1348]: conn=1155 op=4 SRCH attr=dn
Jan 28 22:05:40 server slapd[1348]: conn=1155 op=4 SEARCH RESULT tag=101 err=0 nentries=0 text=
Jan 28 22:05:40 server slapd[1348]: conn=1155 op=5 SRCH base="dc=intranet,dc=company,dc=com,dc=pl" scope=2 deref=3 filter="(&(objectClass=posixGroup)(gidNumber=513))"
Jan 28 22:05:40 server slapd[1348]: conn=1155 op=5 SRCH attr=dn description
Jan 28 22:05:40 server slapd[1348]: conn=1155 op=5 SEARCH RESULT tag=101 err=0 nentries=1 text=
Jan 28 22:05:40 server slapd[1348]: conn=1155 op=6 UNBIND
Jan 28 22:05:40 server slapd[1348]: conn=1155 fd=30 closed
```

PS. Unsuccessful login attempts should not have any influence on the other machine.